# How can I automatically wake up from certain battery percentage for computer sleeping using applescript?

Tags: applescript

Hey guys I'm absolutely new here, and new in applescript. I'm create super simple notification self battery reminder using apple script. but the problem is I want this notification able to self wake up during computer sleep. I using `caffeinate` but only works for display sleep only. Any kind of ideas or `manual` instruction to able solve that.

Here the code

```
set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalChargeCapable")
tell Cap to set {wallPower} to {last word of paragraph 1}
if wallPower = "Yes" then
set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -wO -l | grep Capacity")
tell Cap to set {Available, Max} to {last word of paragraph 2, last word of paragraph 1}
set pct to round (100 * Available / Max)

if pct ≥ 95 then
    do shell script "caffeinate -u -t 1"
    tell application "iTunes" to play
    tell application "System Events"
        set volume 100
        display alert "Your macbook battery is 95%. recommended unplug it now"
        
    end tell
end if

else

set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -wO -l | grep Capacity")
tell Cap to set {Available, Max} to {last word of paragraph 2, last word of paragraph 1}
set pct to round (100 * Available / Max)

if pct ≤ 30 then
    do shell script "caffeinate -u -t 1"
    tell application "iTunes" to play
    tell application "System Events"
        set volume 100
        display alert "Low battery, please plug in now"
        
    end tell
end if
end if
```

when I tried `key code` and `keystroke` still doesn't work
Btw sorry for bad english

Comment: Not attempting to answer your question in this comment, just a suggestion for improving coding. If you use `set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -wO -l | grep '\"Capacity\" = \\|AppleRawCurrentCapacity\\|ExternalChargeCapable'")` then you only have to use one `do shell script` _command_ and call `ioreg` once. Then you can use `set wallPower to last word of paragraph 3 of Cap` and `set {Available, Max} to {last word of paragraph 2, last word of paragraph 1} of Cap` Also, here is an [example IMO of a better way to code](https://paste.ee/p/5wqGd) what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks man but there are some error

Here's the error 

error "Can’t get paragraph 3 of \"    | |           \\\"ExternalChargeCapable\\\" = No\"." number -1728 from paragraph 3 of "    | |           \"ExternalChargeCapable\" = No"

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? If I copy and paste the _code_ at the link in my first comment into **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** it works without issue, sans having to change **iTunes** to **Music**, and the `do shell script` _command_ [returns this](https://paste.ee/p/ebqza). So there is clearly a `paragraph 3`.

Comment: 10.11 (El Capitan) and macbook mid 2010

Comment: What does `set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -wO -l | grep '\"Capacity\" = \\|AppleRawCurrentCapacity\\|ExternalChargeCapable'")` return if you run that by itself?

Comment: Nothing happened when I tried `set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -wO -l | grep '\"Capacity\" = \\|AppleRawCurrentCapacity\\|ExternalChargeCapable'")` on terminal. while I tried `set Cap to (do shell script "ioreg -w0 -l | grep ExternalChargeCapable")` on terminal, it said `"ExternalChargeCapable" = Yes` (if the charger being plug in)